# VSCode BERT ValueError: Unable to access local path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I have written the code for an entity extraction model using `bert` but when I run the `train.py` file I get a value error.

This is the structure of my code with the configuration file in VSCode, I have downloaded bert models from [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert)

[image]

**Error**

```
>> (myenv) PS D:\Transformers\bert-entity-extraction> python src/train.py

Configuration Complete!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/train.py", line 83, in <module>
    model = EntityModel(num_tag = num_tag, num_pos = num_pos)
  File "D:\Transformers\bert-entity-extraction\src\model.py", line 25, in __init__      
    self.bert = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained(config.BASE_MODEL_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 1080, in from_pretrained
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 427, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, kwargs = cls.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\transformers\configuration_utils.py", line 492, in get_config_dict
    user_agent=user_agent,
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\transformers\file_utils.py", line 1289, in cached_path
    raise ValueError(f"unable to parse {url_or_filename} as a URL or as a local path")
ValueError: unable to parse D:\Transformers\bert-entity-extraction\input\bert-base-uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12\config.json as a URL or as a local path
```

How to fix this?

Comment: is there a `config.json`?

Comment: No there isn't an `config.json` file but in the bert uncased folder there is one `bert_config.json` file.

Comment: does BERT want a `config.json` in that folder to describe what to do